# Empty package explorer when opening Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I am opening **Eclipse** to complete my work the package explorer is **empty**.

I created a new project with the same files and when I closed and tried to open it again it was  **empty** again.

I've searched on this issue but I haven't found a solution.

[image]

Comment: stop writing to /dev/null.  On a more serious note, are you sure you are selecting the correct workspace folder?  Do you have any scripts that might be deleting the workspace metadata?

Comment: i select the right one , and how to know this scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a permission problem into your workspace directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Import > Existing Projects in workspace